# Laravel how to execute specific function every time a specific controller's functions are used

Tags: laravel, controller

I am running laravel and i just implemented PHP Excel in order to export excels with data. For security reasons i want to redirect the user if his facebook id is no match with "my administrator facebook id".

My controller is named **ExcelController** and it has different functions inside it.

I do not want to use the below code inside every function so i am trying to find something to execute like `__construct()` - everytime this controller is accessed :

```
if(Auth::user()->facebook_id != env('facebook_id_admin_access')) {
      return redirect()->route('home');
}
```

`env('facebook_id_admin_access')` is an .env variable(like a constant) with the facebook id i want to give access so it can use the specific controller.

I tried creating a `public function __construct(){}` in the controller and put the above code block but it doesn't get called.

Is this possible and how? Should i use `middleware` for that?

> EDITED QUESTION

1) Created a `middleware` **CheckAdminAccess**

```
   */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {

        if(Auth::user()->facebook_id != env('FACEBOOK_ID_ADMIN_ACCESS') || !Auth::check()) {
            return redirect()->route('/');
        }

        return $next($request);
    }
```

2) Updated in `app\http\kernel.php` to

```
protected $routeMiddleware = [
        'admin_access' => 'App\Http\Middleware\CheckAdminAccess',
    ];
```

3) Updated in `routes.php` :

`Route::get('/output/completed', 'ExcelController@completed')->middleware('admin_access');`

But it doesn't seem to work, did i forgot anything?

Comment: [Middleware](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/middleware) is waht you're looking for. The first example answers your question completely.

Comment: you still looking for answer?

Comment: @Quasdunk updated question

Comment: @bluemoon updated question

Comment: Is your config cached. Can you try to call `php artisan config:clear` then re-test?

Comment: @rap-2-h I just tried that, also clear the cache of browser but no changes. In the `.env` file i've put as `FACEBOOK_ID_ADMIN_ACCESS` a wrong facebook id so it won't let me download the excel. Is there any way to check if `middleware` works without implementing any code?

Comment: add a `dd('something')` in your middleware.

Comment: @rap-2-h Nothing happened..It just downloads the excel instantly without redirecting..is that the cause of the problem? In my `routing` -> `Route::get('/output/completed', 'ExcelController@completed')->middleware('admin_access');`

Answer (score 0):

After creating a middleware,

To make it work i changed in my `routes.php` from :

```
Route::get('/output/completed', 'ExcelController@completed')->middleware('admin_access');
```

To :

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth','admin_access']], function() {
    Route::get('/output/completed', 'ExcelController@completed');
});
```